Request Method: POST Status Code: 400 Bad Request Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
import { Restaurant } from "@/types"
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-react"
import { useMutation } from "@tanstack/react-query"
import { toast } from "sonner"

const API_BASE_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL

export const useCreateMyRestaurant = () => {
  const{ getAccessTokenSilently} = useAuth0()
    
  const createMyRestaurantRequest =
    async (restaurantFormData: FormData): Promise<Restaurant> => {
      const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently()

      const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/api/my/restaurant`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
        body: restaurantFormData,
      })
      console.error(response)
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to create restaurant")
      }
      return response.json()
    }

  const {
    mutateAsync: createRestaurant,
    isPending,
    isSuccess,
    error,
  } = useMutation({ mutationFn: createMyRestaurantRequest })

  if (isSuccess) {
    toast.success("Restaurant Created")
  }

  if (error) {
    toast.error("Unable to update restaurant")
  }
  return { createRestaurant, isPending }
}

import { Request, Response } from "express"
import Restaurant from "../models/restaurant"
import cloudinary from "cloudinary"
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const getMyRestaurant = async () => {}

const createMyRestaurant = async(req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const existingRestaurant = await Restaurant.findOne({ user: req.userId })
    if (existingRestaurant) {
      return res
         .status(409)
         .json({message:"User restaurant already exist"})
    }
    const image = req.file as Express.Multer.File
    const base64Image = Buffer.from(image.buffer).toString("base64")
    const dataURI = `data:${image.mimetype};base64,${base64Image}`

    const uploadResponse = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(dataURI)

    const restaurant = new Restaurant(req.body)
    restaurant.imageUrl = uploadResponse.url
    restaurant.user = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userId)
    restaurant.lastUpdated = new Date()
    await restaurant.save()
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Restaurant created successfully" })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went Wrong" })
  }
}

export default {
  createMyRestaurant
}

In Postman it run smoothly but after I make a frontend the error is:

Request Method: POST Status Code: 400 Bad Request Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request URL:
http://localhost:7000/api/my/restaurant
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
400 Bad Request
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

can you add the index.js file in server

first things first check the Content-Type header

when sending FormData in a POST request, the Content-Type header
should not be manually set to application/json or anything else,
browser automatically sets it to multipart/form-data
ensure that CORS is properly configured on your server to accept
requests from your frontend’s origin
since you’re using Multer to handle file uploads, ensure that req.file is populated correctly, if it’s undefined, the file may not be reaching your server correctly

for development purposes you can run chrome without web-security using the commands below:
macOS
open -na Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/temporary-chrome-profile-dir --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials

Windows
start chrome --user-data-dir="%TMP%\temporary-chrome-profile-dir" --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials

Linux
google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/temporary-chrome-profile-dir --disable-web-security --disable-site-isolation-trials

disabling the web-security will let you to continue the development, but you still had to check and fix it on production
